# pageState and viewModelState is null on Page Navigation in UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, prism, prism-6

I am using Prism 6 with UWP. I have a button in MainPage.xaml which redirect to DashboardPage.xaml. In DashboardPage, I am saving the view state in DashboardPage.xaml.cs :

```
protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<string, object> pageState)
        {
            base.SaveState(pageState);

            pageState["viewState"] = 123;
        }
```

and saving view model state in DashboardPageViewModel.cs :

```
public override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingFromEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState, bool suspending)
        {
            base.OnNavigatingFrom(e, viewModelState, suspending);
        }

[RestorableState]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
        }
```

By pressing back button from topbar, I went back to MainPage.xaml. After that, when I navigate to DashboardPage.xaml again, I found that view state and view model states are being null. Which means, in the below code of DashboardPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void LoadState(object navigationParameter, Dictionary<string, object> pageState)
        {
            if (pageState == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            base.LoadState(navigationParameter, pageState);

            if (pageState.ContainsKey("viewState"))
            {
                var data = pageState["viewState"].ToString();
            } 
        }
```

**pageState** is found null.

And, for view model state in DashboardPageViewModel.cs :

```
public async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e, viewModelState);
        }
```

**viewModelState** is null

Comment: Could you share a basic demo project that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: yes sure, I uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8OqH2mGwC7kMWNDNVNJYW5Sa1E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By pressing back button from topbar, I went back to MainPage.xaml. After that, when I navigate to DashboardPage.xaml again, I found that view state and view model states are being null.

From your posted project. I found that you use `NavigationService.Navigate` to navigate to **DashboardPage**. It's right at first time, but after you navigating back to **MainPage** and again navigate back to **DashboardPage**. You are also using the `NavigationService.Navigate` API.

I downloaded Prism's Source Codes and found where the `LoadState` is called:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
{
        ...
    if (navigationEventArgs.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        var nextPageKey = _pageKey;
        int nextPageIndex = frameFacade.BackStackDepth;
        while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
        {
            nextPageIndex++;
            nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
        }

        // Pass the navigation parameter to the new page
        LoadState(navigationEventArgs.Parameter, null);
    }
    else
    {
        LoadState(navigationEventArgs.Parameter, (Dictionary<String, Object>)frameState[_pageKey]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `LoadState` is called inside `OnNavigatedTo` and `PageState` is passed as argument **on condition that the NavigationMode is not New**. For `ViewModelState` it is the similar situation. And for your case, everytime navigating to a page through `NavigationService.Navigate` will create a totally new page, which means `NavigationMode=NavigationMode.New`. Therefore PageState and ViewModelState are null.

From the [NavigationMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationmode) document we can see the `NavigationMode.Forward` fits your requirement.

So, to fix the problem. The only thing that needs to be done is to modify the `OnPageChange` method in `MainPageViewModel.cs` like codes below:

```
private void OnPageChange()
{
    if (_navigationService.CanGoForward())
    {
        _navigationService.GoForward();
    }
    else
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate("Dashboard", null);
    }
}
```